# Transmission and Receiving Rate of a X-Band Antenna

Tags: data-transmission, antenna

What would be a typical transmission and reception rate range for a X-Band Low Gain Antenna for say 300Km from an orbiter? I figured a High Gain Antenna would be difficult to use since it requires accurate transmission rate paths, whereas the Low Gain is omnidirectional.

Comment: Is this a surface to orbiter transmission? Is the orbiter using a low or high gain antenna?

Comment: It is surface to orbiter transmission, and the orbiter would be using a high gain antenna